# Why can't PHP open the file that it has already found?

Tags: php

I'm using:

```
if (file_exists($path))
            fopen($path, "+r");
```

And it returns:

```
Warning: fopen(/var/www/guiademedicos.med/sistema/library/Pixel/views/teste.tpl): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/guiademedicos.med/sistema/library/Pixel/Tools.php on line 39
```

Any ideas as to why this could be happening?
Some additional information is that the permission to both the folder and the file are set to 777.

Comment: Documentation mentions only r+, but I don't think this could cause the problem.
Is everything fine with the upper directories also? Are all of them executable by the relevant user?
Isn't the file maybe a directory or a broken symlink maybe?

Comment: It was just a mistyping, already correct, the problem persists :/

Comment: Which folder and which files have 777 permission? The file you want to open or the php script? Does the 'both' refer to file and folder or to both files and both folders?

Comment: It's solved by changing the file extensio to .phtml. Don't really know what happened, and which was the problem.